# ArcPy from points to lines keeping points attributes?

Tags: arcpy, csv

I have a script in ArcPy that read a CSV file like this:

```
FID,LonDD,LatDD,Length,Depth,Type,Label,Date/Time
1,-1.090261,59.887594,,5,A,Text,041100ZAUG19
1,-1.090261,59.854044,,5,A,Text,041100ZAUG19
1,-1.104367,59.831088,,5,A,Text,041100ZAUG19
1,-1.129053,59.785178,,5,A,Text,041100ZAUG19
2,-0.164150843,60.63374438,,1,B,Text,041100ZAUG20
2,-0.380170968,60.52978211,,1,B,Text,041100ZAUG20
2,-0.436680462,60.5024162,,1,B,Text,041100ZAUG20
2,-0.5844909,60.43050015,,1,B,Text,041100ZAUG20
3,0.311851222,60.34566342,,2,C,Text,041100ZAUG21
3,0.031944655,60.31490018,,2,C,Text,041100ZAUG21
3,-0.283586398,60.28072305,,2,C,Text,041100ZAUG21
3,-0.468049486,60.26297731,,2,C,Text,041100ZAUG21
```

and it creates lines following the FID column (each value of FID correspond to a different line, i.e. FID=1 is the first line and each row is a vertex of the line), but when I open in ArcMap I don't have the attributes.
I lose them when I use `arcpy.PointsToLine_management`.

Is there a way to keep them? Maybe for each point of the line?

This is an extract of the script I use:

```
import archook

# Create AML python environment
archook.get_arcpy()
import arcpy

spRef = r"Coordinate Systems/Geographic Coordinate Systems/World/WGS 1984.prj"

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(r'D:\out', 'test.gdb')

# Make the XY event and save to layer file
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(r'D:\in\data.csv', 'LonDD', 'LatDD', r'D:\in\data', spRef, None)

# Save to layer file
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(r'D:\in\data', r'D:\out\line')

# Convert layer file to gdb. file
arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\out'
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(r'D:\out\line.lyr', r'D:\out\test.gdb\line_points')

# Determine name of new line feature class - takes name of input file
arcpy.PointsToLine_management(r'D:\out\test.gdb\line_points', r'D:\out\test.gdb\line', 'FID')

arcpy.Delete_management(r'D:\out\test.gdb\line_points')

os.remove(r'D:\out\line.lyr')
```

Comment: It's not possible to keep more than a measure value per vertex without building a lookup table for the ancillary data (and picking which attribute is associated with which vertex may be a challenge)

Comment: @Vince does this mean that only points can have more than 1 attribute? Can't I give any attribute to the whole line based on the ones of the points?

Comment: A point layer can have attributes by point. A line layer has attributes by *line*. While it's possible to add attributes per vertex, it's very nearly worst practice (normal form is best practice, which would be one row per vertex).

Comment: After you run your script and created your lines, simply run Join Field and join on FID to pass over the rest of the values as they are all constant per FID.

Comment: @Hornbydd I added this line to my code  `arcpy.JoinField_management(r'D:\out\test.gdb\line_points', 'FID', r'D:\out\test.gdb\line', 'FID')` after `arcpy.PointsToLine_management`, but I don't have the attributes, `line_points` has all the attributes I thought to take them from there. What mistake did I make?

Comment: I've just realised that you are copying your point data into a file geodatabase, you probably don't have a FID field but an OBJECTID field, you need to double check the name of the fields you are joining by. You are also not supplying the final parameter which is the list of fields you want to join.

Comment: @HornbyddI checked and I have `OBJECTID` and `FID`, the difference is that the first is a progressive number and the latter has the same values as in the CSV file. I used `OBJECTID` but the result is the same, no attributes are joined. I didn't supply the list of fields because the documentation says in this way all of them are joined, but I tried also given it and still no attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Hornbydd suggestion I added `arcpy.JoinField_management` to my code, but I made the mistake to switch the input table with the output one.

The right code is:

```
arcpy.JoinField_management(r'D:\out\test.gdb\line', 'FID', r'D:\out\test.gdb\line_points', 'FID')
arcpy.DeleteField_management(r'D:\out\test.gdb\line', 'FID')
```

I added `arcpy.DeleteField_management` because the final result has twice `FID`, if I find a better way to do it, I will update the answer.